# Debugging corona SDK app on real device

Tags: lua, coronasdk

am working on corona SDK  and am developing  app for android in windows environment .
before i used to debug on the simulator

But now i need to do debug on device not in the simulator
 kindly help me friends.

Comment: are u haveing the complete licensed  version.If not u cant do it

Comment: ya i have license can u tell me the procedure to do

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you used for your "local" debugging, you may be able to use the same tool for on-device debugging as well. For example, [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com/) supports on-device debugging for Corona applications. Note that not all debugging functions are going to be available for on-device debugging as `loadstring` function is disabled.